# Strange doings when moving a div

Tags: javascript, dom-manipulation

I want to move multiple DIV with arrow keys and javascript (without jquery).
All my DIV have "position:absolute", etc...
I made a function for this :

```
function move(orig, val) {
    var num = parseInt(orig);
    return ((num + val) + "px");
}
```

And I apply the move function like this :

```
myDiv.style.left= move(myDiv.style.left, moveX);
```

And it only "works" cause I noticed that when one of my DIV has a left style < 0, others DIV with left style > 0 "move" faster than him. So if I repeat back and forth, at the end all my DIV has the same left (didn't try this vertical moves and top value).

Thanks in advance for you help (and excuse me for my bad english).

Comment: Is `moveX` constant? Or try `parseInt(orig, 10)`. If both don't solve the issue, could you provide a jsFiddle demo?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. moveX is not a constant, it's a "velocity" var. It seems that the problem comes from parseInt part. When I replace `var num = parseInt(orig);` by `var num = orig.replace('px','')*1;` It seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect `parseInt` is not appropriate in your case. If you're using non-integers, then adding e.g. `1.5` will effectively act as if you added `2` because of integer rounding. That will inadvertently make it move faster.

You have several options:

- Use `parseFloat` to keep the decimal part.
- Use `+orig.replace("px", "")`, which works with non-integers (or other tricks like `* 1`).

Comment: You're right. But my problem didn't come exactly from Integer rounding . In fact it comes from differences between parseInt applied on negative and positive left value :
-10.5 become -10 (more on the right than normally) and 10.5 becomes 10 (more on the left than normally) so at the end, each DIV has the same left value than the more on the left one.

Thanks for your answer pimvdb

Comment: @Baptiste Pillon: I hadn't considered that; thanks for the follow up!